# Can i set values to only be allowed in a single "group"

Tags: postgresql, constraints, unique-constraint

I have a table similar to that looks something like this:

```
 code | group
------+------
  1   |   a
  1   |   a
  2   |   a
  9   |   b
  9   |   b
  8   |   b
```

Is there a way to set a constraint so that the same code can appear only in one group?

So that for example adding a row `code=3; group=a` would not violate the constraint, but adding a row `code=1; group=b` would be a violation of the constraint.

Comment: 0) the table has no primary key. 1) group is functionally dependent on code, so they could both be squeezed out into a separate code(PK)-> group -table. The original table would only contain the new PK->code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can do it if these fields are in the same table. It looks to me that you have a hierarchy in which `group` is the master level and `code` is detail. I see this can be solved with 3 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE "group" (
    id "char" CONSTRAINT "group_pk" PRIMARY KEY
)

CREATE TABLE "code" (
    id INTEGER CONSTRAINT "code_pk" PRIMARY KEY,
    group_id "char",
    FOREIGN KEY group_id REFERENCES "group" (id)
)

CREATE TABLE "data" (
    id INTEGER CONSTRAINT "data_pk" PRIMARY KEY,
    code_id "char",
    ...
    FOREIGN KEY code_id REFERENCES "code" (id)
)
```

where `data` table represents the table you are talking about.